# Android BlurView issues with SKCanvasView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am attempting to create a view for Android whose background appears to blur the view's content for which it is on top. This is nothing new and has been done before. I based my implementation on what was done here: [Dimezis/BlurView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView).

The approach uses the pre-draw event from the view tree observed to draw a view to an internal canvas. The canvas is backed by a bitmap. A blur is applied to the bitmap before it is drawn to the canvas passed to BlurView's draw method. This approach works well for all standard views/controls and is a common method used to achieve the blur view effect.
However, it does not handle Skia-based drawings that may be on the view that is blurred.

Skia, via `SKCanvasView`, is used heavily for controls within the App so this is kind of a deal breaker if I cannot find a solution. The issue is very odd. Anything that is drawn on the canvas view appears to be scaled and translated when drawn to the internal canvas.

[Screen-Shot - blur label v. blur SKCanvasView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC7bt.png)

The screen-shot show the difference in results from blurring a label with text v. blurring a red circle drawn on an SKCanvasView.

For reference, I've posted a sample project on GitHub. It can be found here: [jaredballen/BlurView](https://github.com/jaredballen/BlurView)

I'd really appreciate any input that can be shared.

Comment: *"scaled and translated"* - sounds like a problem with "coordinates". Specifically, the SKCanvasView perhaps has its own scale and offset (translation). Note that Skia works with device pixels, while Xamarin typically works with DIPs (160 per inch). Perhaps you can change scale and offset of either the SKCanvasView, or the internal canvas used for blurring.

Comment: What is drawn on the SKCanvaisView is correct where it is actually displayed. See my screen-shot in the original post. The BlurViews are on the left side and the views they are blurring are still exposed on the right. The translation and scaling only occur once the view is drawn onto the internal canvas. At this point, a transform can only be applied to the internal canvas which has the view drawn on it, and all of its subviews which include other views besides the SKCanvasView. So there is no way to apply a transform just on the SKCanvasView, unless you traverse the view hierarchy.

Comment: I see. You could change the technique. Instead of blurring during pre-draw, let all drawing go to canvas, thus to internal bitmap. Then it doesn't matter what the sources were. Then blur the desired portion of the bitmap. This *might* require a second bitmap, depending on internal details. Either to hold the area being blurred. Or worst case, the entire bitmap has to be duplicated, so can transfer blurred and unblurred portions separately.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `_rootView?.Draw(_internalCanvas);` the circle `SKCanvasView` is internally rendering itsself using `_internalCanvas` size (same as `_blurView` size) resulting in demonstrated behavour. My guess this could be solved by making `_internalCanvas` of the same size as the `_rootView`, rendering root view as blurred, then clipping and translating the result inside the smaller `_blurView`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion and I did try this approach in the main App. However, I did try it again in the sample App that I posted to GitHub just to double-check. The result of matching the sizing BlurView (and the internal canvas) are the same. The label is blurred correctly but the image in the SKCanvasView is scaled, translated, and cropped.

Comment: @JaredAllen Sounds like you should render the canvasview to a separate bitmap, and have that bitmap be what is composited to the final view. Hmm, a canvasview *does* have its own bitmap, so its unclear why that is different than rendering any other image. Have you tested other images? Or looking at this a different way: why is the canvasview at the wrong **scale**?  Ultimately its "just a bitmap" that has been rendered on. It must be possible to have that bitmap at the same scale as the internal bitmap. Then it should work fine.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I did some more work with the sample App. I found that regardless of wheter or not the SKavasView was being painted in response to being drawn on the root view or in response to the root view being drawn to the internal canvas, it is always given the same dimensions. And from what I can tell, it does not have any transforms applied to it. I'm not convinced there is anything inherently wrong with the current approach. It's like there's some arcane knowledge that I'm missing about how SkisSharp is drawn with respect to a "native" Android view.

Comment: Yep the main blocking issuie is that when SKCanvasView get a Draw invoked it uses the passed canvas dimensions to draw itsself and not its own forms control dimensions..